# Glide, How to display image cache while charging the request?

Tags: android, android-glide

When the internet is slow, Glide takes too long time to show the image, I need to display the image immediately.

Answer (score 12):

1) If your image is not changing rapidly you could use Glide disk and memory caching feature. Define the strategy using `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy)` method. There are several `DiskCacheStrategy` you could use:

- `DiskCacheStrategy.NONE` caches nothing
- `DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE` caches only the original full-resolution image.
- `DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT` caches only the final image, after reducing the resolution
- `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` caches all versions of the image. This is the default behavior

2) If your image changes rapidly you'll need to maybe load the cached image right away and then do the network call to fetch the update and load it if success. There are ways to do this but maybe you wanna look at [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module) and `.concat`

Comment: @Ceaggar, was the answer of any help to you?

Comment: Not really, because what I wanted was to eliminate the lag.
While Glide verifies that the url changes and reloads the new image, I wanted it to display the one already cached, that is,

image 1 = http://awesome.image.com/myawesomeimage.png [cached]
image 2 = http://awesome.image.com/otherimage.png [new to download]

Glide will display myawesomeimage.png while downloading otherimage.png

But I thank you very much for your response, since I see that you have helped other members of the community.